# How to remove the last charactor and replace `:` by `.`

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns `M` and `U` containing employee time record in an Excel sheet but the time format is wrong it is something like `08:13a`. I want it look like `08.13` in order to use subtraction formula like `=U2-M2` to get the difference. so I want to replace `:` by `.` and get ride of the last character using Excel VBA.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show what you've attempted to do, we can help fix it.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, its for `3/26/2015`. The time format is excatly like `08:13a` this and the Date Field format `3/26/2015`. I think excel considered it as text because of `:` and letter `a` so that i can do any mathematical calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if **8:13a** is really 8 hours, 13 minutes, then running:

```
Sub TimeFixer()
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(Mid(r.Text, 1, Len(r.Text) - 1), ":")
        r.Value = TimeSerial(ary(0), ary(1), 0)
        r.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce a time you can use numerically.

**EDIT#1:**

Formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

for example:

[image]

Or in the code replace **Selection** with something like **Range("A1:A100")**
*There are many ways to skin this cat.*

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary's Work like a charm, But is there any way to put the cell range in the formula instead of selecting cells range manually?